# Initialize multiple variables with different parameters

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have the following code in python 3:

```
x = [(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=7))) for _ in range(5)]
```

Is there a better way to initialize multiple (5+) lists with different K values and in range()?

ex:

```
y = [(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=3))) for _ in range(5)]
z = [(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=7))) for _ in range(2)]
a = [(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=4))) for _ in range(3)]
b = [(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=3))) for _ in range(5)]
c = [(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=1))) for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: generate the lists in a loop and append to another list which is declared before the loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the list comprehension in a function and use that repeatedly:

```
def func(k, r):
   return [(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=k))) for _ in range(r)]
```

---

```
y = func(3, 5)
...
c = func(1, 3)
```

If you have the values of `k` and `r` in two lists, you can do:

```
y,..., c =  (func(*t) for t in zip(lst_k, lst_r))
```

Or better still keep the data structure as a list of lists to not worry about the number of targets on the LHS:

```
super_list = [func(*t) for t in zip(lst_k, lst_r)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure: parameterise the arguments:

```
import random
import string

k_val = [3, 7, 4, 3, 1]
r_val = [5, 2, 3, 5, 3]

x = [[(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase, k=k_val[i])))
           for _ in range(r_val[i])] for i in range (len(r_val)) ]
```